# fontawsome icons from a remote server

Tags: font-awesome

We have a 3rd party website that uses include files to add header and footer wrappers to the pages(not our wish but we are stuck with it). We need to change these to reflect our new responsive website currently in development, the wrappers load fine with all image paths working well,apart from some font icons in the footer.
I am trying to load the font icons from the remote server where our new site is located but cannot seem to get them to render. We have tried everything including fully qualified paths to no avail. Is this possible or should we consider another approach.?

Comment: What is your question, be precise. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would like to know if font icons can be used remotely and if yes how